# Maximize over two screens

Tags: unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, window

EDIT: I ended up installing KDE and everything worked as expected. I think that there must be something built into Unity that simply will not allow windows to stretch over two screens in the way I was trying to do it.

---

I'm on 14.04 Trusty with the Unity WM. The computer has two screens, each plugged into the internal display. In the Display settings panel, the two screens are stacked vertically.

All I want is for maximized windows to cover both screens. Actually, what I REALLY need is to do this from a script. I tried wmctrl, but no matter what, windows always stop at the edge of a screen.

If I drag a window across the border and then stretch it manually, it works, but this will not what I need: I need the solution to be something I can automate.

I tried this in on another computer with the same version of Ubuntu but with KDE instead of Unity and it worked. I think it would be overkill to move to KDE just for that, though.

I tried modifying values in CCSM and I tried several other settings, but nothing made windows maximize over both screens and no setting allowed vmctrl to place a window over both screens.

Surely, this must be doable. How can a script place a window over both my screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, I gave up trying to do this in Unity and installed KDE. Everything worked as expected in KDE.

Comment: Disappointed to see no solution was proposed 2 years later.